# Is possible to "sniff" a socket? Socat doesn't work

Tags: socket, tcpdump, socat

This is the situation:
I have two VM (virtual machines) via kvm-qemu
connected via virtual-serial (a socket).
I created the two vm's with this serial configuration:

serial1 (slackware, uses port1 which is ttyS1 or com2)

```
<serial type="unix">
  <source mode="bind" path="/tmp/ppp.sock"/>
  <target type="isa-serial" port="1">
    <model name="isa-serial"/>
  </target>
  <alias name="serial1"/>
</serial>
```

serial2 (unixware use port 0, which is ttyS0 or COM1)

```
<serial type="unix">
  <source mode="connect" path="/tmp/ppp.sock"/>
  <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
    <model name="isa-serial"/>
  </target>
  <alias name="serial1"/>
</serial>
```

The serial works

```
ssh unixware2

cu Slackware1
Connected

slackware1 login:
```

I want to sniff the traffic!
Searching on net i found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/484671/can-i-monitor-a-local-unix-domain-socket-like-tcpdump)
I did that...

```
sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:6004,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/ppp.sock
```

and

```
sudo tcpdump -i any -f 'tcp port 6004' -vv -xX
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

as you can see 0 packet is captured.
I've also tried -i lo but no success.
Of course I have made some operations
(using uux, cu, etc..).

Comment: *"Searching on net they said to do this"* - it would be nice to actually link whatever source you've used. What I would expect from your description though is that you would need to establish the connection to port 6004 instead of connecting directly to the serial port by calling "cu Slackware". socat will then send the traffic to the UNIX domain socket.

Comment: I want to sniff the socket, I have corrected the answer with link

Comment: Not sure which of the several answers in the link you refer to (not that you can actually link to answers - use "Share" on the answer).  But I cannot see that you strictly follow any of the answers but instead try your own (non-working) variation of it.